# Dealing with different types of SitecoreParent

Tags: glass-mapper

Templates `A` and `B` both inherit from Templates `C`.

I have an item that can have either an `A` or a `B` as parent.

How can I use the `[SitecoreParent]` attribute in order to retrieve either according to the circumstances?
I tried with

```
[SitecoreParent]
public C Item { get; set; }
```

but it's always null.

Comment: Have you tried with `virtual` modifier? `public virtual C Parent { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to tell it specifically to [infer the type](https://training.glass.lu/courses/glass-mapper-sc-version-5-training-course/lectures/4929709) of the parent (also, the property should be marked `virtual`):

```
[SitecoreParent(InferType = true)]
public virtual C Parent { get; set; }
```